# Go timeout not firing

Tags: go, timeout

I implemented a few sorting algorithms in Go for fun, and now I'd like to test their performance on random integers. So I wrote the following program. I followed a similar format to: https://gobyexample.com/timeouts

However, it seems like the timeout is not firing properly. Below is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "allanpinkerton.com/algorithms/sorting"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

// Prints out the time elapsed since start
func timeExecution(startTime time.Time, functionName string, inputSize int) string {
    executionTime := time.Since(startTime)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%-20s took %10.4fms to sort %d elements\n", functionName, float64(executionTime.Nanoseconds())/1000000, inputSize)
}

// Generates file with n random ints named integerArray + n
func generateRandomIntegers(n int, filename string) {
    arr := make([]int, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        arr[i] = rand.Int()
    }
    f, _ := os.Create(filename)
    defer f.Close()
    for _, num := range arr {
        f.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(num) + " ")
    }
    f.WriteString("\n")
    f.Sync()
    fmt.Printf("Generated " + filename + " with " + strconv.Itoa(n) + " elements.\n")
}


func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func main() {

    sortingFunctions := map[string]interface{}{
        "InsertionSort":        sorting.InsertionSort,
        "QuickSortLastElement": sorting.QuickSortLastElement,
        "QuickSortRandom":      sorting.QuickSortRandom,
    }
    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
        fmt.Printf("No size specified.\n")
        return
    }
    size := os.Args[1]
    sizeInt, err := strconv.Atoi(size)
    checkError(err)

    arr := make([]int, sizeInt)
    for i := 0; i < sizeInt; i++ {
        arr[i] = rand.Int()
    }
    fmt.Println("Generated " + size + " integers.")

    mainChannel := make(chan string)
    for k, v := range sortingFunctions {
        newArr := make([]int, len(arr))
        copy(newArr, arr)
        go func(name string, v interface{}) {
            start := time.Now()
            v.(func([]int))(newArr)
            result := timeExecution(start, name, len(newArr))
            mainChannel <- result
        }(k, v)
    }

    for _ = range sortingFunctions {
        select {
        case result := <-mainChannel:
            fmt.Printf(result)
        case <-time.After(time.Second):
            fmt.Println("Timeout")
        }
    }

    return
}
```

The top is just a bunch of helpers, but the there's something funny going on with the main function. I ran `go install` and ran it against 150,000 elements, and got the response below:

```
Generated 150000 integers.
QuickSortLastElement took    15.0037ms to sort 150000 elements
InsertionSort        took  7599.5884ms to sort 150000 elements
QuickSortRandom      took    15.1697ms to sort 150000 elements
```

Clearly insertion sort took over 7 seconds, but the timeout should fire after 1 second. Is there any reason for the timeout not to fire?

So I tried switching out my custom sorting program out for the sort.Ints function from the sort package by changing sortingFuncs map into:

```
sortingFunctions := map[string]func([]int){
    "InsertionSort":        sort.Ints,
    "QuickSortLastElement": sort.Ints,
    "QuickSortRandom":      sort.Ints,
}
```

And the problem was solved. So it's my custom sorting functions that are preventing the timeout from being fired. Is there something that I have to add to those functions to make them run in parallel?

Here is a concatenated version with all the code in the playground.
https://play.golang.org/p/SBgDTGyUyp

Comment: You had asked about question formatting, check the link under "edited <date>" to see what was changed along edit comments.

Comment: By the way, in Go you probably should be using the [`testing`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks) package for standardized benchmarks.

Comment: BTW2: `sortingFunctions` should be defined as `map[string]func([]int)` so you don't have to do a type assertion.

Comment: When posting a question about code you should try and make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), for Go it's often something that can be run on the Go playground. Not only does that make it a lot easier on those trying to help but it can also help you track down your problem yourself in the process. In this case the [mcve](https://play.golang.org/p/6nK9onlmtN) I tried to come up with appears to have the key elements of your code but does not show any issues and runs as expected. Since you left out a lot of code it's hard to know what's going on.

Comment: I just noticed as well that your third line (15ms) should have been printed before the second (7599ms) if they were running in goroutines (unless `GOMAXPROCS` is 1 and the functions are such that they never yield the CPU) are you sure the code presented here is what you ran? It almost looks it was running without the `go` keyword in the loop. E.g. like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/IqGE0EmWcK).

Comment: I think you're right! I checked and GOMAXPROCS was set to 1. I must've missed some setup, I suppose?

Comment: It shouldn't have mattered for this since your sorting, even though CPU bound, should have allowed the Go scheduler to switch to other goroutines anyway. I seem to recall back around ~Go 1.2 they changed it to run the scheduler on some function calls so that tight CPU bound loops were less likely to starve out other goroutines.

Comment: Final(?) by the way comment: with respect to using the `testing` package, you should be able to drop something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/8moIHfiWGx.go) into a `*_test.go` file in your package and use `go test -bench=.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted on the Go playground gives the following output:

```
Generated 90000 integers.
InsertionSort        took  4465.6230ms to sort 90000 elements
QuickSortLastElement took    11.2758ms to sort 90000 elements
QuickSortRandom      took    11.6547ms to sort 90000 elements
```

I suspect the fact that you are not seeing the timeout being called is due to the fact that `InsertionSort` does make any function calls, and thus [does not allow](https://golang.org/doc/go1.2#preemption) the scheduler to switch between goroutines.  Since Go by default uses only a single thread, everything else has then to wait until `InsertionSort` has finished.

To test this hypothesis, I tried calling the program with GOMAXPROCS=4 (allowing the Go scheduler to use 4 operating system threads): In this case I get the output

```
Generated 90000 integers.
QuickSortRandom      took    21.1900ms to sort 90000 elements
QuickSortLastElement took    11.4538ms to sort 90000 elements
Timeout
```

as expected.  (Curiously, for GOMAXPROCS=2 the behaviour is not deterministic, sometimes the timeout triggers and sometimes it does not.  I did not try to find out why 2 threads are not always enough here.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `time.After(time.Second)` inside the final loop, you are reseting the timeout every time a result arrives.  Instead, try

```
timeoutChannel := time.After(time.Second)
for _ = range sortingFunctions {
    select {
    case result := <-mainChannel:
        fmt.Printf(result)
    case <-timeoutChannel:
        fmt.Println("Timeout")
    }
}
```

The above code now catches the timeout correctly.  It still does not work quite as intended, because the contents of the loop always are executed three times (since `sortingFunctions` has three elements), and any timeout counts towards these three iterations.  Using your code from the go playground I now get the following output:

```
Generated 90000 integers.
QuickSortRandom      took     9.4268ms to sort 90000 elements
Timeout
QuickSortLastElement took     8.6096ms to sort 90000 elements
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the OP's initial problem since the times in question where 15ms, 7999ms, and 15ms. (I.e. more than the timeout elapses between a pair of send/receives on `mainChannel`).

Comment: It's also not clear that perhaps the OP *did* intend for the timeout to apply to just a single iteration (e.g. perhaps they did want to timeout only if it's been awhile since any progress/results have been reported).

Comment: @DaveC is correct. I intended to timeout the program if there hasn't been any output for n seconds.

Comment: @AllanPinkerton, then running your existing code as "GOMAXPROCS=4 go test.go" does solve your problem (see my other answer)?  If you don't want to use environment variables, e.g. on Windows, you can add "runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)" as the first line of `main` to get the same effect.